# Discord.py error; ffmpeg not found even after installing and configuring it in Environment Variables

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

So I'm trying to integrate the music bot feature in my Discord bot, I'll just link the code I suspect something's wrong with.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import praw
import random
import os
import json
import ffmpeg
import youtube_dl

# music command
@client.command(pass_context=true)
async def play(ctx, url):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    player = await voice.client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
```

and here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Trayambak\Desktop\Akihiko\bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ffmpeg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'
[Finished in 52.353s]
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know of a module named `ffmpeg`. Maybe you've created your own but from what I get in your message it's not the case.

FFmpeg is a command line tool built on a lot C libraries. It is not natively available as a Python package. I know two ways to use it with Python:

- You can install FFmpeg on the computer you're running code on and run native FFmpeg commands. (Information in this [tutorial](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/))
- Other option, you use `ffmpeg-python`(link to the [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/) and the [git](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)). It's a library of python bindings that creates a link between Python functions and the FFmpeg functions/commands.

Each method has its pros and cons. But I would summerize it with:
If you want to build a simple FFmpeg-based tool with no critical use, go with the Python bindings, it's the simplest imo. If you want to use FFmpeg commercially anytime soon, take the time and learn how it really works and use the command line.